# Ajax JQuery For Loop returning only last item in array

Tags: jquery

Newish JQuery person here. I'm trying to use an Ajax call to pull a gif that corresponds to every word of this "chapter" string. My loop is just giving me back the last word "stairhead" a whole bunch of times.

Can anyone help me spot the problem?  Thank you!

```
var chapter = "STATELY, PLUMP BUCK MULLIGAN CAME FROM THE STAIRHEAD";
var chapterArray = chapter.split(" ");

for (i=0; i<chapterArray.length; i++){

var currentWord = chapterArray[i];

var queryURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + currentWord + "&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";
    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: 'GET'
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            var results = response.data;

    var gifDiv = $('<div/>');
    var word =$('<div/>');
    var gif = $('<img/>');
...
```

Comment: your loop works fine,  can you describe the problem in more details?

Comment: @kapreski you're right, the loop was fine.  I wasn't appending the results, so it was only giving me the last item, instead of all of them. Thank you.

Comment: Try to use `chapterArray[i]` directly inside queryURL. Don't use any variable to store it. Might that be a reason for the issue.